# How can I use a probability distribution in python class?

Tags: python, function, class, probability-distribution

Say I have the following class:

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, pevtype):
        self.pevtype = pevtype
```

How can I write a function which uses a probability distribution to determine whether the vehicle is an EV or a PHEV?

For example, the function setVehicle() would enable:

```
>>> v1.pevtype = 'EV'
>>> v2.pevtype = 'PHEV'
```

Comment: Do you want to pick one of `'EV'` or `'PHEV'` at random, rather than passing an explicit argument?

Comment: @chepner I want to choose either 'EV' (p=0.3) or 'PHEV' (p=0.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html). It takes a list of items that you want to chose from, and you can pass it the probability associated with each item as well. In the following example, I stored the information in a `dict`, where the `keys` are the items you want to chose from, and the `values` are the respective probabilities:

```
import numpy as np


class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, pevtypes):
        self.pevtype = np.random.choice(
            list(pevtypes), p=list(pevtypes.values())
        )

car_types = {'EV': 0.3, 'PHEV': 0.7}

# for a single car
car = Vehicle(car_types)

print(car.pevtype)

# for 2 or more cars e.g. like this
cars = [Vehicle(car_types) for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Say you would do this for a different no of vehicles (100,200,300...) such that it would return vehicles (v1, v2,...,vn) with the attribute EV or PHEV. How would you do that?

Comment: You just loop over the assignment. I edited the example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) from the standard library.

```
import random
values = ['EV', 'PHEV']
for _ in range(10):
    result = random.choices(values, weights=(0.3, 0.7))
    print(result[0], end=' ')
```

Example output: `PHEV EV PHEV PHEV PHEV PHEV PHEV PHEV EV EV`

---

Additional info: You're not limited to just 2 options and you can get multiple results.

```
import random
values = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for _ in range(10):
    result = random.choices(values, weights=(1, 4, 10), k=2)
    print(result)
```

Example output:

```
['B', 'C']
['B', 'C']
['C', 'C']
['C', 'C']
['C', 'B']
['C', 'B']
['B', 'C']
['C', 'C']
['C', 'C']
['B', 'C']
```

---

This is a possible implementation including the code from the question. Here I assume that the pev types and their probability are fixed in the code, so I made them an attribute of the class `Vehicle`. This can be changed as needed. Note that the distributions are relative and don't have to add up to exactly `1.0`.

```
import random

class Vehicle:
    pev_types = {'EV': 0.3, 'PHEV': 0.7, 'X': 0.2}

    def __init__(self):
        self.pev_type = self._get_random_pev_type()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Vehicle (pev type:{self.pev_type})'

    def _get_random_pev_type(self):
        return random.choices(list(self.pev_types), weights=self.pev_types.values())[0]

print(', '.join(str(Vehicle()) for _ in range(10)))
```

Example output:

```
Vehicle (EV), Vehicle (EV), Vehicle (X), Vehicle (PHEV), Vehicle (PHEV), Vehicle (X), Vehicle (PHEV), Vehicle (PHEV), Vehicle (PHEV), Vehicle (PHEV)
```

Comment: You can also store the choices and the weights together: `values = {'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 10}` and `random.choices(values, weights=values.values(), k=2)`. Even in older Python versions, where `dict` order wasn't preserved, it is *consistent* between multiple iterations.

Comment: Thank you for adding this suggestion. I thought about adding that example but I feared it would look like a rip-off from the other answer.

Comment: I think the most important part of this answer is that it's not using an external library.

Comment: You can rip it off if you like! At what point does it make sense to use `numpy` for something like this though? I would have thought that `numpy` is faster, but maybe not.